# Compensation for damaged buggy on Vietnam Airlines

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines, vietnam-airlines

I recently returned from Vietnam and the airline at the airport in Vietnam issue the badge at the gate. When I arrived in Heathrow there is a part in the buggy broken. After complaining at the airport I got a report and then I contacted the airline who said they gave me a tag in Vietnam that release them from compensating for any damage. I understood others airlines compensate/fix if they damage a baby buggy. I don't know what to do now as if I contact my travel insurance as the part is £80 and my excess is £50 I have to pay most of it.
Is there any one else to complain about the behaviour of the airline?

Comment: How recently? And how soon after the flight did you write to the airline requesting compensation?

Comment: I wrote them 2-3 days after.

Answer (score 2):

> I understood others airlines compensate/fix if they damage a baby buggy.

Most other airlines in the world offering carriage on an international ticket would be bound by the [Montréal Convention](http://www.iata.org/policy/consumer-pax-rights/Documents/mc99-full-text.pdf), which would make them strictly liable for damage caused to checked baggage while it is in their care. The Convention also makes it very easy to bring claims against a foreign carrier in your home country, either as the passenger or as the passenger's insurer (through subrogation). In the UK you can actually bring a claim online for a few pounds.

Unfortunately, Vietnam is [not a signatory](https://www.icao.int/secretariat/legal/List%20of%20Parties/Mtl99_EN.pdf) to the Convention.

Vietnam has set up a [parallel legal structure](http://img2.caa.gov.vn/2016/07/28/00/27/2006-Civil-Aviation-Law.pdf) that, in the places concerned with airline liability, largely resembles the Convention, but it is a foreign law while you are in the UK, and for an £80 claim, it is not going to be sensible to raise a dispute.

> airline who said they gave me a tag in Vietnam that release them from compensating for any damage

The only positive thing I can say, is that it seems under Article 167 of Vietnam's Civil Aviation Law, such a "tag" is null and void.

> Art. 137 (1) Any agreement by the carrier with the passenger, the consignor and consignee on exoneration of the limits of liability referred to in paragraph 1 of Article 166 shall be null and void.

You can try writing back to their complaints department, but I think to be honest you are not going to get your £80 back. Your best bet is to discuss the matter with your insurer, or possibly raise a Twitter storm.

Answer (score 1):

At this point I'd personally just give up. Your losses of 80 pounds would not be worth a lawsuit and at this point this is your only option.

Comment: Not sure what you really give extra to the previous answer. it's really up to me if I want to give up. You just gave your opinion rather than explain anything.